# Spring Hadoop Java Based Job Creation

Tags: spring, hadoop

is there away to accomplish this in java as opposed to xml:

```
<hdp:job id="mr-job"
  input-path="/input/" output-path="/ouput/"
  mapper="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.TokenizerMapper"
  reducer="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.IntSumReducer"/>
```

[Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-hadoop/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/springandhadoop-mapreduce.html#creating-a-hadoop-job)